# How do I hide or show DataTables.net colums?

Tags: javascript, datatables

Based on the API docs at [DataTables site](http://datatables.net), I created the following javascript function to show only one specific table at a time:

```
function ShowColumn(columnNum) {

    var table = $('#MemberStatisticGrid').dataTable();

    $('#SelectedMetricList option').each(function (index) {
        table.fnSettings().fnSetColumnVis(index, false);
    });

    table.fnSettings().fnSetColumnVis(columnNum, true);
}
```

However, this fails with the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<1> has no method 'fnSetColumnVis'`

I don't get why I am getting this, as according to the API docs this is how you call it. Furthermore, when I view the available methods and properties on the `fnSettings()` via the chrome console, I don't see a `fnSetColumVis` method.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried just using `table.fnSetColumnVis`? That works for me.

Comment: oh, I was reading the code samples wrong somehow, that worked.